# Linker error when adding QAxWidget to empty project

Tags: c++, windows, qt, activex, qaxwidget

I have an empty project, and I added a QAxWidget in Qt Designer. The project compiled before adding the QAxWidget, but now it fails with this linker error:

```
mainwindow.obj:-1: error: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall QAxWidget::QAxWidget(class QWidget *,class QFlags<enum Qt::WindowType>)" (??0QAxWidget@@QAE@PAVQWidget@@V?$QFlags@W4WindowType@Qt@@@@@Z) referenced in function "public: void __thiscall Ui_MainWindow::setupUi(class QMainWindow *)" (?setupUi@Ui_MainWindow@@QAEXPAVQMainWindow@@@Z)
```

Should I change something in my .pro file, add some module perhaps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer after some searching, it turned out I need to add this to my .pro file:

```
LIBS += qaxcontainer.lib
```